# flutter) How do I create a widgets in a tabbed position of screen?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a whiteboard app.

I would like to create text box widgets at the potision I want as shown in the image below.
May I know how to create a widget in the position(offset) where I've tapped?

[image]

Comment: My idea is using an Detector to detect and get position of Tap. then Using Stack and Positioned to draw an Editor in that positioned. i thing it can work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i comment before. I have an idea: using `GestureDetector` to detect Tap action and postion of Tap, then using `Stack` and `Positioned` to create an `Editor` like this.

***** localPosition and globalPosition is differences, carefull.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var editorEnable = false;
  var editorPosition = Offset.zero;

  void closeEditor() {
    print('editor closed');
    setState(() {
      editorEnable = false;
      editorPosition = Offset.zero;
    });
  }

  void newEditorAt(Offset position) {
    print('editor created at $position');
    setState(() {
      editorEnable = true;
      editorPosition = position;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapUp: (details) {
          if (editorEnable) {
            closeEditor();
          } else {
            newEditorAt(details.localPosition);
          }
        },
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.grey),
            if (editorEnable)
              Positioned(
                left: editorPosition.dx,
                top: editorPosition.dy,
                child: TextEditor(),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextEditor extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 200,
      height: 50,
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is result

[image]